# memoir, verbatim: how to remove blank space symbol in verbatim text

Tags: memoir, verbatim

Why the following MWE produce the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
why in the verbatim text is shown blank space symbol \verb!verbatim text!?
\end{document}
```

How to remove blank space symbol in verbatim text?

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1167 but marked as closed, I'll check....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is a bug I haven't released a fix for yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memoir has an embedded copy of the verbatim package and that gives errors with the latest kernel update.

For now you can use this fix

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup
 \catcode`\ =\active%
 \def\x{\def\@vobeyspaces{\catcode`\ \active\let \@xobeysp\@vobeytabs}}
 \expandafter\endgroup\x
\makeatother
```

I plan to remove the embedding and instead load the `verbatim` package and add a few things to it (though some features will be removed).

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that I'm faced with back compatibility of LaTeX and their packages. I was asked to renew one of mine text book, which I finished in 2014. I have a lot of headache to compile one perfectly worked LaTeX files. I already rewrote some style definition, but at some I'm a bit a lost. So, it seems that will ask for more help if I will not find solutions myselfs ;-)

Comment: @Zarko I have a similar problem with my Danish LaTeX book. Haven't looked at it in many years and nowadays it cannot compile as some features I added to a package interface no longer works.

Comment: I keep finger crossed for your book ....I just discover new problem. Regarding used fonts in original files I use `[scaled=0.82]{luximono}` fonts, which now at use verbatim text throw error `pdflatex.exe (file ul9r8r): Font ul9r8r at 492 not found`. About this I would ask neq quastion ...

Comment: Did you install `luximono` (I use that in my book as well). It is not a part of texlive, so you need to use `getnonfreefonts` to install it. If you already have it in `texmf-local` it might need to be enabled. (I have this problem each year when I upgrade TL)